# Automatically mirror a directory in Ubuntu

Tags: 12.04, dropbox, realtime

Running Ubuntu 12.04

I have a library of personal files and documents stored in Dropbox. I want the Dropbox folder to be automatically mirrored to a directory in the local machine, as a backup to the backup. I want it to be done automatically. In other words, each time I add a file/folder to the Dropbpx, that file/folder is copied automatically to the second location on the local drive.

Any ideas, tips or advices would be appreciated.

Best regards

Answer (score 5):

I don't think (or know) how " each time I add a file/folder " could be done easily. But if you are OK with say a once a minute sync, I believe you could put together `rsync` and `cron` into a workable solution. I am not sure how efficient rsync is with data on the order of GBs, possibly made mostly of binary data?

A question arises though. If you want to mirror each change immediately, how is that a backup? Wont a mistake/corruption get mirrored instantly as well?

Checkout [rdiff-backup](http://rdiff-backup.nongnu.org/) if you want a proper backup solution.

But frankly, I would expect your backup drive to fail before dropbox store does.

Comment: That's a good question and didn't think about it! I was thinking of something like a RAID 1 but I think it's not an ideal solution. Any suggestions?

Comment: @Latvian with rsync you can restore to specific time (seconds ;) ) so you can revert back to before that mistake :) But I agree: it is NOT a backup.

Comment: @Rinzwind Are you talking about rsync itself or one of its derivatives. Afaik you need something like rdiff-backup to be able to revert.